# theos libxml2: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, dylib, tweak, theos

I'm use [theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started) write a tweak and need use libxml2. I had add LDFLAGS like this:

```
widget_INSTALL_PATH = /Library/WeeLoader/Plugins/
widget_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit CoreGraphics
widget_LDFLAGS = -lxml2
```

the code in my xxx.m

```
#import "BBWeeAppController-Protocol.h"
#import <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
```

than make , error:

```
error: libxml/HTMLparser.h: No such file or directory
```

in xcode need set 'header search path' -> $SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2, but how to do in "[theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use CFLAGS.
If you haven't already take a look at the Theos Makefile page http://uv.howett.net/ipf.html

Comment: Thanks. LDFLAGS is required. so the code sample: `widget_LDFLAGS = -lxml2 widget_CFLAGS=-I$(SYSROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`